# ggplot2 adding percentages to bars grouped on x-axis/ remove missing data yet still added in

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes", Mac Mojave 10.14.6.

I have the following ex code:

```
dat:
         'data.frame':  261 obs. of  22 variables:
         $ name            : Factor w/ 261 levels "Some Person",..: 28 32 38 171 216 257 37 43 48  63 ...
         $ title           : Factor w/ 257 levels ""," Some title of Text",..: 181 11 212 60 221   100 105 85 189 56 ...
         $ s          : Factor w/ 85 levels "Alberta",..: 56 51 32 77 15 15 56 43 6 67 ...
         $ year            : int  1992 1992 1992 1992 1992 1992 1993 1993 1993 1993 ...
         $ N               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
         $ Z         : Factor w/ 202 levels "","Some Person",..: 35 8 95 4 117 NA NA 68 115 46 ...
         $ Z2        : Factor w/ 150 levels "","Some; Other; People ",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 95 NA 138 ...
         $ P        : Factor w/ 5 levels "Academic","Business",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
         $ E      : int  1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
         $ P1             : Factor w/ 7 levels "AD","AP","B",..: 5 5 5 6 NA 5 5 5 5 5 ...
         $ H               : int  11 8 1 18 NA 13 1 14 NA 33 ...
         $ RF              : int  4 4 2 4 NA 4 1 1 NA 2 ...
         $ Em          : Factor w/ 231 levels " Austin","head of dept",..: 92 187 51 84 21 163 26 149 47 24 ...
        $ M1          : int  NA 1 NA NA NA NA NA 0 NA NA ...
        $ M2            : Factor w/ 217 levels ""," some methods used in writing": NA 208 NA NA NA 1 NA 40 NA NA ...
        $ M3     : Factor w/ 3 levels "M","Ql", "Qt",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
        $ R            : int  3 12 24 12 7 7 3 4 4 1 ...`
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar graph where the x-axis is 'year' & the y-axis is M3.

I have tried this code:

`ggplot(Df2, aes(x = year, y = prop, fill = M3)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position="fill")`

I get a nice fill graph but no percentages in the bars (totaling 100% for each year).

[image]

So I found some code to try and fix this: (doing back to original data)

```
percentData <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% count(M3) %>%
     mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
```

There are some NA values in M3 I want to remove.

```
percentData <- percentData[!is.na(percentData$M3), ]
```

However, checking my data I see the following:

```
percentData
A tibble: 61 x 4
Groups:   year [23]
    year M3       n ratio
   <int> <fct>  <int> <chr>
 1  1996 Ql     11 64.7%
 2  1997 M      3 18.8%
 3  1997 Ql     10 62.5%
 4  1997 Qt     2 12.5%
 5  1998 M      6 40.0%
 6  1998 Ql     7 46.7%
 7  1998 Qt     1 6.7% 
 8  1999 M      4 33.3%
 9  1999 Ql     6 50.0%
10  1999 Qt     2 16.7%
```

I can get a graph with percentages for each year by doing the following:

`ggplot(rudat,aes(x=years,fill=factor(Methodology)))+
    geom_bar(position="fill")+
    geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio),
              position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))`

However, it includes NA values.

[image: graph]

This is an issue because, for example, 1996 shows 64%-- I need it to show 100% for "Ql" because all data available were "Ql"-- the NA values are somehow still being counted. For other years, the 3 levels of M3 should also total 100%, given NAs removed.

Further, I am not 100% sure how to get the % for each year in the bars once I resolve this.

Since this is a database I built in Numbers, I can just remove all of the NAs myself in a new file and run that data, but there has to be some way to do this just using R code.  I won't always have that luxury.

I followed the code form here.

http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/01/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-4-stacked-bar-plots.html

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I resolved this by creating a different dataset where I truncated the data to what I needed and removed NA values.  I then re-ran the code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

percentData <- dat %>% filter(!is.na(M3)) %>% count(year,M3) %>%
     mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n)))
because there have NA level,it can not del